# Running app on remote tomcat server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, war

I transfered my WAR file on the external server by Tomcat Manager. I can see the this file in putty console but I don't see my application on "List Applications" in my Tomcat Manager. Probably I have to do something else but I don't know what.

Comment: When I try to run this app in browser I get a communicate: "HTTP Status 503 - This application is not currently available"

Comment: Can you run yourr application on remote server?Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat v.6. Could you tell me how I should correctly run my app on remote server?

Comment: Just a guess:Can you restart the remote server?

Comment: I have problems with restart Tomcat because when I try execute "sh shutdown.sh" I get communicate about lacking of conf/server.xml file. I don't have shell files in other localization such as var/lib/tomcat6.

Comment: Tried deploying it using the App Manager's deploy option? Just select the war file and is should hot deploy in seconds

Comment: I did it in that way but my app doesn't appear on List application in tomcat manager.

Comment: And I got this communicate 'This application is not currently available' when I try enter in my app in browser.